# How to get lines separating semi circle with equal intervals on Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, vector, images

[image]

Inkscape

Im trying to recreate this image. How can I get  lines in the semi-circle between with equal intervals (shown in image).
I have tried to use a collection of squares and then curve it (edit path by node) but it doesnt seem to work.
The colour gradient and numbers are fairly understandable to get, just having a tough time making sure that the lines in the semicircle are equally spaced.
TIA

Comment: Recreating the lines has got a couple of useful suggestions and there could be even more. I guess the gradient fill in your example probably is not drawn as you want. I would make the colors to flow along the  arc, not linearly from left to right. like this  https://i.stack.imgur.com/M31JS.png It's not as easy as linear gradient in Inkscape, but it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could approach it. One would be to make a line of squares, group them, and use the Bend Live Path Effect to distort it into an arc. Another would be to draw one line, move the rotation centre to the origin of the circles, duplicate, rotate 15 degrees, then repeat.  Holding down CTRL as you click and drag to rotate constrains it to 15 degree increments, or you could use the Transform Rotate panel to use a different angle.

[image]